# How to change high and low whisker color in boxplot highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, boxplot

This is the link to the fiddle

> https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/box-plot-styling/

Below are the plotOptions.

```
plotOptions: {
        boxplot: {
            boxDashStyle: 'Dash',
            fillColor: '#F0F0E0',
            lineWidth: 2,
            medianColor: '#0C5DA5',
            medianDashStyle: 'ShortDot',
            medianWidth: 3,
            stemColor: '#A63400',
            stemDashStyle: 'dot',
            stemWidth: 1,
            whiskerColor: '#3D9200',
            whiskerLength: '20%',
            whiskerWidth: 3
        }
    }
```

This boxplot shows high and low values in green color. In my case I need to change the high value(Q1) color in red and low value color in green.
[image]

How can I do this.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible in Highcharts by default - related github issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6796

> Currently each box is a single SVG shape and a border is applied by
> stroke parameter which cannot be "separated" for smaller edges. As a
> result, you can apply only single color.
> Your goal requires a rebuild core of boxplot, so we cannot threat it as a bug, but feature request.

---

As a workaround you can render custom paths to cover one of the existing whiskers, for example:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var series = this.series[0],
      attr,
      paths;

    series.points.forEach(function(point) {
      paths = point.whiskers.d.split('M');
      attr = {
        d: 'M' + paths[1],
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
      };

      if (point.customHigh) {
        point.customHigh.attr(attr);
      } else {
        point.customHigh = this.renderer
          .path()
          .attr(attr)
          .add(series.group);
      }
    }, this);
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vcefbk46/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: can you please explain below code segment?

    if (point.customHigh) {
        point.customHigh.attr(attr);
      } else {
        point.customHigh = this.renderer
          .path()
          .attr(attr)
          .add(series.group);
      }

Comment: Hi @kathy genelier, Sure - I store the rendered path as the `point.customHigh` property to use the same element after chart is redrawn (for example if chart size is changed) and only change the element position and dimensions.